# Username behind URL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello Stack overflow currently I'm kind of stuck with my user_profile/username_here.
The problem is that you can fill in every username you want and it still will show the made up username if you put it behind the '/' well I got that filtered out but now how do I let up show the username of the user that is logged in behind the URL?
I'm also using URL rewriting.
the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9-\._]+)(\/)?                    /profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here is the code I'm using for the user_profile.php:

```
<?php
    require_once('db.php');
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        header("location: access_denied.php");
    } else {    

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];
    $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tab where username='$username' AND firstname='$firstname' AND lastname='$lastname'");


    if($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
        $username = $row3['username'];
        $firstname = $row3['firstname'];
        $lastname = $row3['lastname'];
    }



?>
<html>
    <body>
        <table width="398" border="0" align ="center" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
            <td height ="26" colspan="2">Profile info</td>
                <td><div align="right"><a href="log_out.php">Logout</a></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="129" rowspan="5"><img src="<?php echo $picture?>" width="129" height="129" alt="no image found"/></td>
                <td width="82" valign="top"><div align="left">Username:</div></td>
                <td width="165" valign="top"><?php echo $username ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="82" valign="top"><div align="left">Firstname:</div></td>
                <td width="165" valign="top"><?php echo $firstname ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="82" valign="top"><div align="left">lastname:</div></td>
                <td width="165" valign="top"><?php echo $lastname ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p align="center"><a href="index.php"></a></p>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Where do I need to put the code so that the username that is currently is logged in behind the url?
Explanation is welcome to since I'm fairly new to PHP.
Also if you see any errors please say so.

Comment: Adding it to every URL you generate might be a good idea

Comment: how do you generate the url ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DO NOT USE MySQL_*** -- It has been deprecated in PHP 5.5. Use `MySQLi` or `PDO` instead.

Your code you can place anywhere you want. Since you have the variables set, all you have to do is build your link.

```
<a href="profile/<?php echo $username; ?>">
```

This will build the link as such: `http://domain.tld/profile/username`

Comment: Thanks man.
Is there a way I can convert all MySQL_* to PDO or MySQLi without getting troubles? I acutally think it will be very hard since I have multiply files with MySQL_* and none PDO or MySQLi.
Any way i can convert them without any trouble?

Comment: It's like any program that is switching API's, it's going to take time to learn and to implement. It'll be better in the end since you'll be up to date and theoretically, more secure. Possibly look into a class someone made for either one and that may help.

Comment: Aahh okay I really hoped there was an easy way but I guess not. Time to start learning again then.
thanks for the help provided.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<p align="center"><a href="index.php?name=<?php echo $username; ?>"></a></p>
```

but you need to set your htacces to view it as index.php , whitout the extra param

Comment: Why would you do that, if the OP has already designed "pretty" urls? He also has a `profile.php` to handle it.